# Is it possible to fetch latest posts from multiple wordpress installations (without multisite) to display on a single homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have multiple wordpress installations on different subdomains, and i needed to list the latest posts from each installation on the homepage. Do i need to have a single installation (multisite) for this, or is it possible from multiple installations?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull latest post from different sites via RSS feed.  There are [plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-multi-importer/) for this task or you can code yourself.  If you want to code it yourself see below:

usage:

```
<?php $feed = fetch_feed( $uri ); ?>
```

This example will retrieve and display a list of links for an existing RSS feed, limiting the selection to the five most recent items:

```
<h2><?php _e( 'Recent news from Some-Other Blog:', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></h2>

<?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );

// Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
$rss = fetch_feed( 'http://example.com/rss/feed/goes/here' );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly

    // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5. 
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 5 ); 

    // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

endif;
?>

<ul>
    <?php if ( $maxitems == 0 ) : ?>
        <li><?php _e( 'No items', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink. ?>
        <?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>"
                    title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

sources: [Wordpress Feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds), [Wordpress Fetch Feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed).